# how to handle modifying database simultaneously in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

some code like this(execution when uploading an image):

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.get(id=album_id)
index = gallery.photo_num +1                #index will be used in later
gallery.photo_num = index
gallery.save()
```

It works well when uploading image one by one,but if I upload several images at the same time,using multi-upload jQuery plugin.the "gallery.photo_num" will be disorderly

How can i modify my code so that I can avoid this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Django 1.4+, you can use [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update):

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.select_for_update().get(id=album_id)
```

That will lock the row until an update operation occurs.